# Some doubts related the architecture of this Spring MVC project architecture. Is it not using the Spring features?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, architecture, spring-data

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I am finding some doubt related a project (found in a tutorial) that handle Hibernate DAOs in a strange way.

The situation is the following one:

there are 2 XML configuration file, the first one is **spring-servlet.xml** that describe the servlet mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewresolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/images/" mapping="/img/**"></mvc:resources>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/css/" mapping="/css/**"></mvc:resources>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/js/" mapping="/js/**"></mvc:resources>

</beans>
```

The second one is the **spring-security.xml** that contain the Spring Security settings. There is not something like the **root-context.xml** (or **applicationContext.xml**) file that contains the beans that are shared between all servlets in a webapp.

Ok by the way, as you can see, there are not Hibernate configuration or DAO beans declaration in my XML configuration.

To configure\use DAOs class it do in the following way, this is one contrller method (that handle a registration fomr in which the user can register a new account in the system):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doSignUpProcess(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("signup");
    String message = "";

    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {
        try
        {
        List<FileItem> data = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

        String username = data.get(0).getString();
        String password = data.get(1).getString();
        String repassword = data.get(2).getString();
        String gender = data.get(3).getString();
        String vehicle = data.get(4).getString();
        String country = data.get(5).getString();

        String image = new File(data.get(6).getName()).getName();

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setGender(gender);
        user.setCountry(country);
        user.setVehicle(vehicle);
        user.setImage(image);

        if(password.equals(repassword))
        {
            /*Signup_Model sm = new Signup_Model();

            //message = sm.doSignUp(username, repassword, gender, vehicle, country, image);
            message = sm.doHibernateSignUp(user);*/
            message = RegisteryDAO.getUserDAO().doHibernateSignUp(user);
            String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "//WEB-INF//images//";

            data.get(6).write(new File(path + File.separator + image));

        }
        else
        {
            message = "Password does not match..please try again";
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            message = "Please try again....";
        }
    }
    mav.addObject("message", message);
    return mav;
}
```

As you can see in the previous method, to store a new **User user** object on the database it do in this way:

```
message = RegisteryDAO.getUserDAO().doHibernateSignUp(user);
```

Where **RegisteryDAO** is something like a DAO factory class:

```
public class RegisteryDAO {

    public static com.demo.dao.layer.ProductsDAO productsDAO;
    public static com.demo.dao.layer.UserDAO userDAO;

    static{
        productsDAO = new ProductsDAO();
        userDAO = new UserDAO();
    }

    public static com.demo.dao.layer.ProductsDAO getProductsDAO() {
        return productsDAO;
    }

    public static void setProductsDAO(com.demo.dao.layer.ProductsDAO productsDAO) {
        RegisteryDAO.productsDAO = productsDAO;
    }

    public static com.demo.dao.layer.UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public static void setUserDAO(com.demo.dao.layer.UserDAO userDAO) {
        RegisteryDAO.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

}
```

in which is declared and created a new static **UserDAO** object that implement my DAO, this one:

```
public class UserDAO implements com.demo.dao.layer.UserDAO{

    public String doHibernateLogin(String username, String password){
        try{
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateConnection.doHibernateConnection();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();

            List<User> user = session.createQuery("From User where username='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"'").list();

            session.close();

            if(user.size() == 1) return "login success" ;
            else return "Please try again...";
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return "Please try again...";
        }
    }

    public String doHibernateSignUp(User user){
        try{
            Session session = HibernateConnection.doHibernateConnection().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(user);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return "Sign Up Successfully...";
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "User is already there with this username";
        }
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(String username){
        try{
            Session session = HibernateConnection.doHibernateConnection().openSession();
            List<User> users = session.createQuery("From User where username = :username")
                                .setParameter("username", username).list();
            session.close();
            if(users != null && users.size() == 1){
                return users.get(0);
            }else{
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in this **UserDAO** class the Hibernate SessionFactory (used to retrieve the Hibernate Session to store the object on the DB) is retrieved in this way:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateConnection.doHibernateConnection();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

calling the **doHibernateConnection()** on an **HibernateConnection** class in which it is configured the connection to the database

```
public class HibernateConnection {

    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory doHibernateConnection(){
        Properties database = new Properties();
        database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
        database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring");
        database.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                            .setProperties(database)
                            .addPackage("com.demo.pojo")
                            .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                            .addAnnotatedClass(Products.class);

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());

        return sessionFactory;

    }

}
```

So I am pretty new in Spring and I do not have much experience with architectural aspects but it seems to me that this example is pretty horrible because it manually handle the database configuration and the DAOs object creation (it create a factory but the Spring dependency injection is a factory).

So it seems to me that it is pretty horrible because it is a Spring project but it is not using the most important Spring features.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something? (maybe it is pretty usual)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is not taking advantage of Spring dependency injection. Just to make it clear `<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controllers">` scans for bean creation.

Comment: this whole thing is pretty bad. having the daos catch exceptions and return strings is terrible.

Comment: I'd recommend using Spring Data JPA for your DAOs